# How to find $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^2{x}}{x^2}\,dx$?

Tags: integration

Find the integral

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^2{x}}{x^2}\,dx=? \tag{1}$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\tan^2{x}}\,dx=?\tag{2}$$

I know this

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2{x}}\,dx=\pi\ln{2}$$

But for $(1)$ and $(2)$ I can't find it. Thank you someone can find it.

And the [wolf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%28tan%5E2%28x%29%29%2Fx%5E2dx) can't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of your integrals exist. The integrands are positive and have (non-integrable) singularities at points where $\tan^2 x$ is $+\infty$ and $0$ respectively.

Comment: Hello,I don't understand your meaning. I guess your mean this two integral all not exsit?

Answer (score 0):

here is the description by photo why both integral not converge on ${0\to\infty}$

here is why ?

for the $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2 }{\tan^2x}dx$

its the area under the blue line from $0$ to $\infty$

if you look at the picture its seem that the area=$\infty$

[image: 1]

for the $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^2 x}{x^2}dx$

also it seem that the area=$\infty$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\tan^{2}\left(x\right) \over x^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
&=
\int_{-\pi/2}^{0}
{\tan^{2}\left(x + \pi/2\right) \over \left(x + \pi/2\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
=
\int^{\pi/2}_{0}
{\cot^{2}\left(x\right) \over \left(x - \pi/2\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
\sim {1 \over x}\quad\mbox{when}\quad x \sim 0
\end{align}

So, what ?